# I want to change PHP to TypeScript

Tags: php, node.js, typescript

I want to convert this PHP script to TypeScript (nodejs).

```
$fruits = [
    'APPLE'=> [
        'color'=>'red',
        'size'=>'small'
    ],
    'BANANA'=>[
        'color'=>'yellow',
        'size'=>'middle'
    ]
];

echo $fruits['APPLE']['color'];

type info = {
  color: string,
  size: string
}

const fruits['APPLE']: info = {color:'red',size:'small'}
```

I get an error.

Comment: "I get an error" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? What is the error message? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Did you convert the code manually? Please provide the resulting NodeJS code, and also the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

In TypeScript, you can define an object with a similar structure to your PHP array.

```js
type FruitInfo = {
  color: string;
  size: string;
};

const fruits: Record<string, FruitInfo> = {
  APPLE: {
    color: 'red',
    size: 'small',
  },
  BANANA: {
    color: 'yellow',
    size: 'middle',
  },
};

console.log(fruits['APPLE'].color);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. It is convention to capitalise the first letter of `type` for clarity and readability.

```js
type Info = {
  color: string,
  size: string
}
```

2. Not correct JS syntax.

```js
const fruits['APPLE']: info = {color:'red',size:'small'}
```

```js
const fruits = {
  APPLE: {
    color: 'red',
    size: 'small
  }
}
```

3. Assign a type directly or use a type alias.

```js
const fruits: { [key: string]: Info } = {
  'APPLE': { color: 'red', size: 'small' },
  'BANANA': { color: 'yellow', size: 'middle' }
};
```

```js
type Fruits = {
 [key: string]: Info
}

const fruits: Fruits = {
  'APPLE': { color: 'red', size: 'small' },
  'BANANA': { color: 'yellow', size: 'middle' }
};
```